# How to get dynamically images from strings.xml

Tags: android

Hello I have added some images in drawable folder and after that I have refer that in `strings.xml`
Now I want to get dynamically the images so how I can do that, I found this code but for this code I need to give the id of image manually

this is `strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/one</item>
        <item>@drawable/two</item>
        <item>@drawable/three</item>
       <item>@drawable/four</item>
       <item>@drawable/five</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and this is the java code

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
images .getResourceId(i, -1)
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));

imgs.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String names[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fi);
for (String string : names) {

    }
or
for(int i=0; i<names.length ;i++){

}
```

Like this you can access all the elements in the array